# Move parent child picture by 1px with a timer

Tags: javascript, image, replace, timer, increment

I’m trying to recreate Space Invaders. But only in Javascript without jQuery etc.
Now I create for the Rockets a “family”:

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.setAttribute('src', 'Rakete.gif');
image.setAttribute("style",
  "position:absolute; left:" + x2 + "px; top:bottom; bottom:55px;");
```

And I use this to add it to the body:

```
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Now my question: how can I replace the `bottom:55px;` every second by `+1px`?

I have this all in a function with a timer. My problem is only that I dont know how to replace the `bottom` of *every* child. I need to increase the `bottom` for every child.

Comment: What do you think `top:bottom;` is going to do?

Comment: i have delete top:bottom^^ its do nothing because i used bottom:57px; forgot to edit.

Comment: Few question: so all the script mentioned  is in a function which gets called every second ? And thus you have multiple images floating on screen ? and x2 I would assume a random number ?

Comment: Hello, no its this: var x2 = x +57;
So the height from the space invader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s easier to set a class for all such images first:

```
image.setAttribute("class", "rocket");
```

Your timer needs to look like this:

```
var rockets = document.getElementsByClassName("rocket"); // Gets all elements with class “rocket”
setInterval(function(){
  var maximumHeight = window.innerHeight; // maximum value for bottom before element gets removed
  for(var i = 0; i < rockets.length; i++){ // Now, iterate over every element with class “rocket” with a for loop
    rockets[i].style.bottom = (Number( // Convert the following into a number
      rockets[i] // the element
        .style // its CSS data
        .bottom // the bottom property
        .match(/[\+\-]?(?:\d*\.?\d+)/) // the number part of it (in any format)
    ) + 1) // increment!
    + "px"; // plus the string 'px'
    if(Number(rockets[i].style.bottom.match(/[\+\-]?(?:\d*\.?\d+)/)) > maximumHeight){
      // If maximum height is exceeded
      rockets[i].remove(); // Remove that child
    }
  }
},
1000); // 1000ms = 1s
```

Or summarized:

```
var rockets = document.getElementsByClassName("rocket");
setInterval(function(){
  var maximumHeight = window.innerHeight;
  for(var i = 0; i < rockets.length; i++){
    rockets[i].style.bottom =
      (Number(rockets[i].style.bottom.match(/[\+\-]?(?:\d*\.?\d+)/)) + 1) + "px";
    if(Number(rockets[i].style.bottom.match(/[\+\-]?(?:\d*\.?\d+)/)) > maximumHeight){
      rockets[i].remove();
    }
  }
}, 1000);
```

This simply manipulates the CSS data every second.

There’s just one thing to note: …`.match(/…/)` will return an *`Array` if a number is found or `null` if nothing is found* (e. g. if the `bottom` property hasn’t been set yet and is empty or otherwise invalid). This doesn’t matter for `Number()`! `Number(['42'])` still returns the number `42` and `Number(null)` safely returns `0`.

If you actually have your own fallback number (e. g.) you can use the `||` OR operator:

```
rockets[i].style.bottom =
  (Number(rockets[i].style.bottom.match(/[\+\-]?(?:\d*\.?\d+)/) || 55) + 1) + "px";
```

---

### ECMAScript 2015+ approach

```
const rockets = document.getElementsByClassName("rocket"),
  numberPattern = /[\+\-]?(?:\d*\.?\d+)/;

setInterval(() => {
  const maximumHeight = window.innerHeight;

  Array.from(rockets).forEach((rocket) => {
    rocket.style.bottom = (Number(elem.style.bottom.match(numberPattern)) + 1) + "px";

    if(Number(rocket.style.bottom.match(numberPattern)) > maximumHeight){
      rocket.remove();
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, although I completely missed the “every child” part of the question in the first revision. It’s included now… Kyuubi, tell me if it works for you, I’ll edit anything that’s missing into the answer!

Comment: So, can I use this in any way with image.SetAttribute?

Comment: What do you mean by “_with_ `image.setAttribute`”?

Comment: You can use the `var rockets` part and the interval part _after_ all of your definitions of `image`.

Comment: its oeky, it works. Now i must only do that the rockets get remove if they touch top

Comment: Can I let remove now the "child" where have a greater height then the window.innerHeight?

Comment: @KyuubiDDragon Yep, I updated the answer. Just check for the condition and remove them. You can adjust the `maximumHeight` variable (e. g. `window.innerHeight + 5` or `window.innerHeight - 7` or whatever suits your case).

Comment: Its okey, this work, my last question is, can u explain me this thing: (/[\+\-]?(?:\d*\.?\d+)/)

Comment: @KyuubiDDragon Oh yeah, this is the ultimate RegEx for all number formats. It matches any sign (`+`, `-` or none), integers or floats (`45` or `4.525`), with a single 0 before the `.` or not (`0.455` or `.455`), but _not_ non-number stuff like `425.`, `.`, `+`, `6.3.7` or `7+.34` although it may match a part of either of those.